# unable to infer compiler target triple for

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to compile a fresh checked out clang version.
I have followed the instruction in http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html for "On Unix-like systems" and got this error:

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/ran/dev/clang/llvm/projects/compiler-rt'
make/platform/clang_linux.mk:16: *** "unable to infer compiler target triple for /home/ran/dev/clang/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang".  Stop.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little late maybe, but I just ran into the same problem; could fix it by setting `g++` for the `CXX` environment variable:

```
export CXX=g++; make
```

Comment: You can even use `CXX=g++ make` without exporting the variable for later commands.

Comment: never late... I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when building with a separate GCC toolchain. The configure script found the correct version of libstdc++ but the build did not for some reason. I fixed it by adding `/my/toolchain/lib` and `/my/toolchain/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is same with @wds.
Check with the command:
`ldd /home/ran/dev/clang/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang`
and then add the missing library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.